# Can I load isolated instances of an unmanaged dll in a C++/CLI wrapper

Tags: c#, dll, c++-cli, wrapper, unmanaged

I have an unmanaged DLL (unmangaged.dll) in a C++/CLI wrapper.  The unmanaged.dll is a subcomponent of a control that is instantiated in several places on the screen.  I each control instances to have its own instance of the unmanaged.dll (since each unmanaged.dll maintains a different state).

Is there any way to instantiates the same unmanaged.dll so as to have to completely separate states?  (e.g. different settings within each unmanaged.dll instance.)

Unfortunately everything I read about unmanaged.dll in C++/CLI wrappers is that all calls are static.

Thanks

Comment: Of course the moment after posting I find that what I probably need is a Runtime Callable Wrapper (RCW)  
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bwh56xe.aspx
Numerous Q&As on StackOverflow for my reading...

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of "instance of native DLL in a process" in Windows. Only one copy of a native DLL can be loaded into a given process.

You can:

- have multiple instances of objects created by the DLL
- load DLL into as many processes as you need and use some sort of Inter Process Communication (IPC) to talk to it from main process.